# How can loopback addresses be assiged in a Linux VRF?

Tags: networking, routing

I create a Linux [VRF](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/vrf.html) with

```
ip link add vrf-blue type vrf table 10
ip link set dev vrf-blue up
ip link set dev eth2 master vrf-blue
ip ro add default via 192.168.3.202 table 10
```

Then I run a command in that VRF, a shell in this example. It works well for external adresses, but there are no loopback addresses:

```
ip vrf exec vrf-blue sh
# (in the new shell)
ping -c1 -W1 20.0.0.1   # Works
ping -c1 -W1 127.0.0.1  # Doesn't work
```

Many programs assumes the loopback addresses, 127.0.0.0/8 and ::1/128. I have so far googled on "linux vrf loopback" and tried to set local routes in table 10, but can't get it working, so

How can loopback addresses be assiged in a Linux VRF?

```
# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

ip rule show lists the "local" table at prio 0, higher than "l3mdev-table", so loopback is handled before VRF.

```
# tcpdump -i any icmp
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
07:47:15.923179 lo    In  IP localhost > localhost: ICMP echo request, id 27859, seq 1, length 64
07:47:15.923190 lo    In  IP localhost > localhost: ICMP echo reply, id 27859, seq 1, length 64
```

A tcpdump in main VRF shows icmp request/reply, but the reply doesn't reach the "ping" program running in the VRF.

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.raw_l3mdev_accept=1` does not help

Comment: Still not working but I have more info. `ip rule show` lists the "local" table at prio 0, higher than "l3mdev-table", so loopback is handled before VRF. A tcpdump in main VRF shows icmp request/reply, but the reply doesn't reach the "ping" program running in the VRF. "sysctl -w net.ipv4.raw_l3mdev_accept=1" does not help.