# Binding local applications in a VRF

Tags: networking

In Linux, by default there is a loopback interface `lo` with the ip address `127.0.0.1/8` to which local applications can bind to.

It is impossible to bind an application locally inside a vrf to this loopback interface, for example:

> ip link add vrf100 type vrf table 100
> ip vrf exec vrf100 python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1
> OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Question is, how can I create a loopback interface in a vrf, perhaps with a different ip address like 127.0.0.2 in which I can bind local applications to:

> ip vrf exec vrf100 python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.2 ??? how to make this work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my initial requirement is that I run an app within a vrf and it has a management interface which I would like to bind to localhost, e.g.

`ip vrf exec vrf100 myapp --adminif <localhost in vrf100> --userif <physical interface in vrf100>`

I found a working solution like this:

```
ip link add vrf100 type vrf table 100 #create vrf with table 100
ip link add lo-vrf100 type dummy      #add dummy interface that will serve as our loopback
ip link set lo-vrf100 master vrf100   #enslave the interface to vrf100
ip addr add 127.0.0.2/8 dev lo-vrf100 #add ip to this interface
ip link set vrf100 up
ip link set lo-vrf100 up
```

Now, if we look at the policy routing table it looks like this (rule 0 gets handled before 1000, and so on):

```
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

If we look at the routing table local:

```
ip route sh table local
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

Then we see that the ip range `127.0.0.0/8` is handled here, but our vrf is handled in the special table [l3mdev-table] which will be processed later.

```
ip route sh table 100
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo-vrf100 proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.2
local 127.0.0.2 dev lo-vrf100 proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.2
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo-vrf100 proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.2
```

So the solution is to create a rule to handle our ip 127.0.0.2 before the `from all lookup local` entry in policy routing.

```
ip rule add table local priority 100 #have an identical entry but with a higher prio
ip rule add from 127.0.0.2 table 100 prio 50
ip rule add to 127.0.0.2 table 100 prio 51
ip rule del priority 0 #delete the original local rule
```

Eventually the policy routing table looks like this:

```
ip rule sh
50:     from 127.0.0.2 lookup 100
51:     from all to 127.0.0.2 lookup 100
100:    from all lookup local
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And the sample python http server in my first post works ok:

```
ip vrf exec vrf100 python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.2
Serving HTTP on 127.0.0.2 port 8000 (http://127.0.0.2:8000/) 
ip vrf exec vrf100 wget http://127.0.0.2:8000 #downloads file sucessully
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I am a bit new to VRF myself, but I think that lo would just have to be a member, FYI:

[How can loopback addresses be assiged in a Linux VRF?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739196/how-can-loopback-addresses-be-assiged-in-a-linux-vrf)

But here's what I think:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

the interface is a loopback; it's not a forwarding interface and it has it's own table `local`

```
ip route show table local
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 192.168.1.12 dev wlp114s0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.12 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev wlp114s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.12
```

Here's my two cents, you don't really need to assign that to a VRF if you're listening on `127.0.0.1` because it's not going anywhere anyway.

On the other hand, VRF will completely isolated unless you create rules with `ip rule` to lookup the VRF table, so you could essentially assign an interface to a VRF, assign it an address, and as long as you dont have a rule routing into it's routing table it's isolated. Any interface you assign to a VRF it's routes go into it's corresponding table, though so if you assign your host / default gw interface to the VRF then those routes will also be in that table; the alternative is using `ip rule` to setup routing between tables.

If I can offer you my perspective:

```
sudo ip netns exec _netcrave ip route show table 130
192.0.0.4/30 dev vma130 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.0.5 
local 192.0.0.5 dev vma130 proto kernel scope host src 192.0.0.5 
broadcast 192.0.0.7 dev vma130 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.0.5 

sudo ip netns exec _netcrave ip route show
10.0.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 linkdown 
10.254.0.0/30 dev igwsl127 proto kernel scope link src 10.254.0.2 

ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp114s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.12 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp114s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp114s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.12 metric 600
```

typically the way you create a rule to lookup a table goes like this:

`ip netns exec _netcrave ip rule add to 192.0.0.4/30 table 130` and then you have something that looks like this:

```
sudo ip netns exec _netcrave ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
999:    from all to 192.0.0.4/30 lookup 130
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

typically what `ip vrf exec` is for is when you want to bind as your source address, so for example like `ip vrf exec red130 ping 192.0.0.6` would make sure I'm pinging from 192.0.0.5 if 192.0.0.5's interface is actually assigned to that VRF, otherwise you shouldn't need to use vrf exec, the interface is visible the routing table isn't. However if you were using NetNS you certainly would need to use `ip netns exec` because otherwise it would not find the interface.

Here's the other thing that comes to mind:

```
sudo ip netns exec _netcrave ip route show table local
local 10.0.0.1 dev docker0 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.0.1 
broadcast 10.0.255.255 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 linkdown 
local 10.254.0.2 dev igwsl127 proto kernel scope host src 10.254.0.2 
broadcast 10.254.0.3 dev igwsl127 proto kernel scope link src 10.254.0.2 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

you'll notice in my other local table

```
local 192.168.1.12 dev wlp114s0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.12 
    broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev wlp114s0
```

you could in theory make a loopback route to self and add it to this table in fact maybe I'm mistaken but I think that is the intention here:

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/vrf-loopback-interface-into-global-table/td-p/3192007

Comment: also with NetNS unlike VRF you can't really just create a route rule to get from one NetNS out or to another and instead you need a veth pair, like the best way to conceptualize VRF is to think of it as a virtual gateway, and the host is also a gateway not unlike a virtual gateway, and then suddenly it all sorta makes sense and VRF is to layer 3 as bridge is to layer 2 and I have to think where has this been all of my life? Steep learning curve but so useful. I'll be interested to see if you find another answer but I'm at a loss for a better one unfortunately

Comment: Thank you I will analyze your answer, but one thing that stands:

"Here's my two cents, you don't really need to assign that to a VRF if you're listening on 127.0.0.1 because it's not going anywhere anyway."

My scenario is that I have an application that that binds to a physical interface enslaved in a vrf. This application also has an option to select a management interface. Ideally I would bind this management interface to a loopback 127.0.x to not expose it outside the machine:

ip vrf exec vrf100 myapp --admin-if <ideally localhost> --user-if <physical interface enslaved in vrf>

Comment: I'm sorry I really hope I didn't come across as pompous, I don't consider myself an expert on anything really, but especially not this and that's really all I meant by "my own two cents." Also I started thinking about it and imagined that might be where you were going with that; I think it might just be that you need a route in the local table for that to work but it's pushing the extent of my knowledge of this; I will keep an eye on this though because I'd like to understand it better myself.

Comment: Hey, so you got me on the right track because I totally forgot to consider the policy routing table and the built-in tables such as local, especially now that when adding vrfs it is implicitly handled by the l3mdev-table.
I got something working, which previously wasn't, whether it is a clean solution I don't know, but it serves my purpose so thank you ; )